# What is the best way to filter result on JOIN (sql)

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a doubt since a little time ago... what is the best way to filter the entries on a sql join.... i mean, is better on the WHERE clause or on the ON of the join??

For example, what is better? This snippet using the WHERE

```
SELECT 
    customer.users_id AS CustID, 
    FROM customer 
    LEFT JOIN visit ON customer.users_id = visit.CustID
    WHERE visit.active = 1
```

Or this other way (that filter on the ON):

```
SELECT 
    customer.users_id AS CustID, 
    FROM customer 
    LEFT JOIN visit ON (customer.users_id = visit.CustID AND visit.active=1)
```

Thank you.

Comment: The first one is the better response.

Comment: My gut is telling me that there are situations where the two will not give you the same answer (although I can't think of one off the top of my head). Regardless, in this situations they should give you the same answer, and the second one "should" be more efficient. However, the SQL interpreter is rather smart so I would assume that the statements would run in the same amount of time. Therefore, it comes down to style. In general, having a where clause is better style because it doesn't effect both tables in the JOIN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on type of situation whatever is. Here is some text on both:-

First one works as Inner Join, without where it returns all rows from left table including those are `null` in right table. Where condition return all those rows which have `visit 1`. Means it reduce all those rows from result which have active other then `1 or null` rows correspondence to left table

Example:-

```
custome_id visit
1          1
2          1
```

Second one returns rows which have `null` entries corresponding to right table.

Example:-

```
custome_id visit
1          1
2          1
3          null
4          null
```

Note:- In your both statements customer_id can't be null as it have o/p from left table only.

Answer (score 1):

Historically for me, its more efficient to use the **and** statement on the **join** instead of adding it to the where clause.

```
SELECT 
customer.users_id AS CustID, 
FROM customer 
LEFT JOIN visit ON (customer.users_id = visit.CustID AND visit.active=1)
```

There are cases where both cases could be more efficient, but for me I prefer using the **and** in the join statement. I believe if its used in the **where** clause when the query runs it will have to index everything in the **visit** table then filter the results based on **visit.active =1**. This where in my experience its quicker to use the and statement and the performance is to do with how the query optimizer indexes the data.

Update: For me when dealing with millions of records I notice better performance where said above. If the # of records are smaller maybe there is no difference for you.